Rotational motion of motorcycle on wall of death?
I assume you're familiar with the set-up of the 'wall of death'. (Basically, a motorcycle drives in circles in a horizontal plane on the inside curved surface of a  non-smooth cylinder whose axis of symmetry is vertical.)
If we look at the motorcycle free-body diagram from the RF of someone on the ground, we see there is a moment about the bottom of the wheel. This is an inertial RF (I'm pretty sure it is, at least. Although, I wouldn't be able to explain why it is!) So the motorcycle should rotate about this point. I'm pretty sure it doesn't. Although I admit it's hard to judge because the point on the bottom of the wheel is always moving in this RF. So my analysis in this RF seems flawed.
In the motorcycles RF though, things make sense iff I assume the centrifugal force acts through the motorcyles COM. Iff that is the case, we don't get any moment on motorcyclist, about any point (it seems like) and this seems consistent because the motorcycle wouldn't be rotating in this RF.
So what makes my analysis in the stationary observer's RF (seem like it is) wrong?
And is it right to say that the centrifugal force in a rotating body's own RF always acts through it's COM? I just noticed it had to in this case, but is this true for all cases? If so, what's the deeper reason why?

can you explain what the "wall of death" is? (in an edit, not as a reply to this comment)

The rider is never purely horizontal unless his track is curved downards.

@JAlex. Yes, I realise that. The surface they ride on is always vertical in this setup.

Could you clarify which moment you mean in the inertial RF? Is it due to the weight, or another force?


If we look at the motorcycle free-body diagram from the RF of someone
on the ground, .... This is an inertial RF (I'm pretty sure it is, at
least. Although, I wouldn't be able to explain why it is!)

This is not an inertial reference frame. An inertial observer experiences no proper forces. The observer in this case experiences the force of gravity when he is standing on the ground. Better to call the reference frame of the observer standing on the ground a non rotating reference frame.

And is it right to say that the centrifugal force in a rotating body's
own RF always acts through it's COM?

No, that is not correct. Here is a simple demonstration that the centrifugal force does not necessarily act at the COM:

In the diagram, the mass of the rider and the motorbike are treated as two point masses (red points). The mass of the rider (m2) happens to be at the centre of Wall of Death (WOD), so there is no centrifugal force acting at that point, because centrifugal force is a function of distance from the centre of rotation. All the centrifugal force in this case is located at the lower point mass m1 representing the mass of only the motorcycle. The COM is located between m1 and m2, so the centrifugal force is not acting at the COM. In this case the force of gravity acting at the COM is balanced by a greater centrifugal force acting at a lower point. The centrifugal force only acts at the com if the object really is a single point particle.
To get a more accurate estimate of the location that the centrifugal force is acting at, the bike and rider should be divided into more point masses. For example, if the bike and rider are divided into 3 chunks, each represented as a point mass, the radius that the centrifugal force acts at can be found as using the following formula:

Sum up all the moments of inertia:

$$ I_m = m_1 r_1^2+m_2 r_2^2+m_3 r_3^2$$
where $r_n$ is the distance of each point mass $m_n$ from the centre of the wall of death (WOD).

Sum up the moments of mass:

$$M_m = m_1 r_1 + m_2 r_2 + m_3 r_3 $$

Divide $I_m$ by $M_m$ to get the effective rotational radius:

$$R_r = \frac{I_m}{M_m}$$
To find he effective rotational mass, divide the total moment of mass by the effective rotational radius:
$$M_r = \frac{M_m}{R_r}. $$
The effective rotational mass is just a mathematical device like the reduced mass used in orbital calculations.
A single point mass ($M_r$) at this radius with angular velocity ($\omega$) will have the same centrifugal force as all the individual masses with the same angular velocity and it will also have the same moment of inertia as all the individual point masses.
The combined centrifugal force of the system of point masses is given by:
$$F_c = M_r \omega^2 R_r$$
$R_r$ is the distance from the centre of the WOD. To find the height (h) of this point from the contact point of the tyre, the formula is $h = (R - R_r)/\cos{\theta}$, where R is the radius of the WOD. h is not usually the same as the height of the COM, but for large R relative to the height of the bike, using the COM height is a reasonable approximation.
